# ECMAScript is not working in SharePoint 2013 content editor webpart

Tags: javascript

> ECMAScript is not working in SharePoint 2013 content editor web-part.Please let me know issue in the below code.

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(filldata, "sp.js");

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
     var itemId = 49;
     var listItem;       
            var clientContext;
            function filldata() {

                this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {

                    this.web = clientContext.get_web();
                    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("list name");
                    this.listItem = list.getItemById(itemId);               
                    clientContext.load(this.listItem);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail)); // this statement not executing.
                }
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you on a minimal download strategy page? You can tell if you are because your URL ending will look like this: '/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Page.aspx' instead of just '/SitePages/Page.aspx'

Comment: Above code is working fine in application pages by adding below code.                                 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function () {
        
        //  filldata();
        });

Comment: Generally i try to put in script editor webparts. You can try with that.

Comment: Getting same problem with script editor also.